# Updated modern Swift syntax to modern Swift syntax and project will no longer compile

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift2

I recently was pasting a section of code from StackOverflow to my Swift 3 project, the code was written in Swift 2 so I highlighted the section of code and did Xcode -> Edit -> Convert -> Modern Swift Syntax. Not knowing that it would "convert" my entire project.

Now my project has 76 errors, I undid the changes and using source control "pulled" my last "push" to make sure I had a working copy of the application. The code is now the same as it was from before I clicked "convert" but now the code still ***does not compile.*** The code was compiling just fine before I hit "convert" and this is the exact same code but I still have 76 compile time errors.

*How do I make the errors leave my non-erroneous code? Should I just delete my project or (preferably) is there just a simple fix I can perform?*

Comment: Look at your Xcode project settings. You should be able to use a legacy Swift version.

Comment: Try cleaning your project `cmd+shift+k` in Xcode.

Comment: My code is not legacy, it is Swift 3. I just accidentally updated my Swift 3 to modern Swift 3 and now the project won't compile. @nathan

Comment: @Rahul that worked, if you put that as an answer I will accept.

Comment: @brettf added the comment to answer.

Comment: @Rahul can only accept answer after 10 minutes. Will do then. Thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cleaning your project with `cmd+shift+k` in Xcode.

[image]